# How i can use FileSaver.js module without Node.Js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

i have visited a [github](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) code to increase effort for saving a file from javascript/html. We have some problem with to use it, because it mae for node.js. I'v found some demo.js code to save the file from demo.html itself. But, it is useless because i unfortunatly can't edit, because i  wonder it just for demo.html class, and it will become crash if i make a reference to another html file.

This is the code File Saver.js

```
/* FileSaver.js  * A saveAs() FileSaver implementation.  * 1.3.2  * 2016-06-16 18:25:19  *  * By Eli Grey, http://eligrey.com  * License: MIT  *   See https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/LICENSE.md  */

/*global self */ /*jslint bitwise: true, indent: 4, laxbreak: true, laxcomma: true, smarttabs: true, plusplus: true */

/*! @source http://purl.eligrey.com/github/FileSaver.js/blob/master/FileSaver.js
*/

var saveAs = saveAs || (function(view) {    "use strict";   // IE <10 is explicitly unsupported     if (typeof view === "undefined" || typeof navigator !== "undefined" && /MSIE [1-9]\./.test(navigator.userAgent)) {      return;     }   var
          doc = view.document
          // only get URL when necessary in case Blob.js hasn't overridden it yet       , get_URL = function() {            return view.URL || view.webkitURL || view;      }       , save_link = doc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "a")      , can_use_save_link = "download" in save_link       , click = function(node) {          var event = new MouseEvent("click");            node.dispatchEvent(event);      }       , is_safari = /constructor/i.test(view.HTMLElement) || view.safari      , is_chrome_ios
=/CriOS\/[\d]+/.test(navigator.userAgent)       , throw_outside = function(ex) {            (view.setImmediate || view.setTimeout)(function() {
                throw ex;           }, 0);      }       , force_saveable_type = "application/octet-stream"      // the Blob API is fundamentally broken as there is no "downloadfinished" event to subscribe to         , arbitrary_revoke_timeout = 1000 * 40 // in ms         , revoke = function(file) {             var revoker = function() {
                if (typeof file === "string") { // file is an object URL
                    get_URL().revokeObjectURL(file);
                } else { // file is a File
                    file.remove();
                }           };          setTimeout(revoker, arbitrary_revoke_timeout);      }       , dispatch = function(filesaver, event_types, event) {          event_types = [].concat(event_types);           var i = event_types.length;             while (i--) {
                var listener = filesaver["on" + event_types[i]];
                if (typeof listener === "function") {
                    try {
                        listener.call(filesaver, event || filesaver);
                    } catch (ex) {
                        throw_outside(ex);
                    }
                }           }       }       , auto_bom = function(blob) {           // prepend BOM for UTF-8 XML and text/* types (including HTML)          // note: your browser will automatically convert UTF-16 U+FEFF to EF BB BF          if (/^\s*(?:text\/\S*|application\/xml|\S*\/\S*\+xml)\s*;.*charset\s*=\s*utf-8/i.test(blob.type)) {
                return new Blob([String.fromCharCode(0xFEFF), blob], {type: blob.type});            }           return blob;        }       , FileSaver = function(blob, name, no_auto_bom) {           if (!no_auto_bom) {
                blob = auto_bom(blob);          }           // First try a.download, then web filesystem, then object URLs          var
                  filesaver = this
                , type = blob.type
                , force = type === force_saveable_type
                , object_url
                , dispatch_all = function() {
                    dispatch(filesaver, "writestart progress write writeend".split(" "));
                }
                // on any filesys errors revert to saving with object URLs
                , fs_error = function() {
                    if ((is_chrome_ios || (force && is_safari)) && view.FileReader) {
                        // Safari doesn't allow downloading of blob urls
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onloadend = function() {
                            var url = is_chrome_ios ? reader.result : reader.result.replace(/^data:[^;]*;/, 'data:attachment/file;');
                            var popup = view.open(url, '_blank');
                            if(!popup) view.location.href = url;
                            url=undefined; // release reference before dispatching
                            filesaver.readyState = filesaver.DONE;
                            dispatch_all();
                        };
                        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                        filesaver.readyState = filesaver.INIT;
                        return;
                    }
                    // don't create more object URLs than needed
                    if (!object_url) {
                        object_url = get_URL().createObjectURL(blob);
                    }
                    if (force) {
                        view.location.href = object_url;
                    } else {
                        var opened = view.open(object_url, "_blank");
                        if (!opened) {
                            // Apple does not allow window.open, see https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html
                            view.location.href = object_url;
                        }
                    }
                    filesaver.readyState = filesaver.DONE;
                    dispatch_all();
                    revoke(object_url);
                }           ;           filesaver.readyState = filesaver.INIT;

            if (can_use_save_link) {
                object_url = get_URL().createObjectURL(blob);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    save_link.href = object_url;
                    save_link.download = name;
                    click(save_link);
                    dispatch_all();
                    revoke(object_url);
                    filesaver.readyState = filesaver.DONE;
                });
                return;             }

            fs_error();         }       , FS_proto = FileSaver.prototype        , saveAs = function(blob, name, no_auto_bom) {          return new FileSaver(blob, name || blob.name || "download", no_auto_bom);       }   ;   // IE 10+ (native saveAs)   if (typeof navigator !== "undefined" && navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {       return function(blob, name, no_auto_bom) {          name = name || blob.name || "download";

            if (!no_auto_bom) {
                blob = auto_bom(blob);          }           return navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, name);      };  }

    FS_proto.abort = function(){};  FS_proto.readyState = FS_proto.INIT = 0;    FS_proto.WRITING = 1;   FS_proto.DONE = 2;

    FS_proto.error =    FS_proto.onwritestart =     FS_proto.onprogress =   FS_proto.onwrite =  FS_proto.onabort =  FS_proto.onerror =  FS_proto.onwriteend =       null;

    return saveAs; }(
       typeof self !== "undefined" && self  || typeof window !== "undefined" && window  || this.content )); // `self` is undefined in Firefox for Android content script context // while `this` is nsIContentFrameMessageManager // with an attribute `content` that corresponds to the window

if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports) {   module.exports.saveAs = saveAs; } else if ((typeof define !== "undefined" && define !== null) && (define.amd !== null)) {   define("FileSaver.js", function() {
    return saveAs;   }); }
```

And the demo.js

```
/*! FileSaver.js demo script
 *  2016-05-26
 *
 *  By Eli Grey, http://eligrey.com
 *  License: MIT
 *    See LICENSE.md
 */

/*! @source http://purl.eligrey.com/github/FileSaver.js/blob/master/demo/demo.js */

/*jshint laxbreak: true, laxcomma: true, smarttabs: true*/
/*global saveAs, self*/

(function(view) {
"use strict";
// The canvas drawing portion of the demo is based off the demo at
// http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/
var
      document = view.document
    , $ = function(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }
    , session = view.sessionStorage
    // only get URL when necessary in case Blob.js hasn't defined it yet
    , get_blob = function() {
        return view.Blob;
    }

    , canvas = $("canvas")
    , canvas_options_form = $("canvas-options")
    , canvas_filename = $("canvas-filename")
    , canvas_clear_button = $("canvas-clear")

    , text = $("text")
    , text_options_form = $("text-options")
    , text_filename = $("text-filename")

    , html = $("html")
    , html_options_form = $("html-options")
    , html_filename = $("html-filename")

    , ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
    , drawing = false
    , x_points = session.x_points || []
    , y_points = session.y_points || []
    , drag_points = session.drag_points || []
    , add_point = function(x, y, dragging) {
        x_points.push(x);
        y_points.push(y);
        drag_points.push(dragging);
    }
    , draw = function(){
        canvas.width = canvas.width;
        ctx.lineWidth = 6;
        ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
        var
              i = 0
            , len = x_points.length
        ;
        for(; i < len; i++) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            if (i && drag_points[i]) {
                ctx.moveTo(x_points[i-1], y_points[i-1]);
            } else {
                ctx.moveTo(x_points[i]-1, y_points[i]);
            }
            ctx.lineTo(x_points[i], y_points[i]);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
    , stop_drawing = function() {
        drawing = false;
    }

    // Title guesser and document creator available at https://gist.github.com/1059648
    , guess_title = function(doc) {
        var
              h = "h6 h5 h4 h3 h2 h1".split(" ")
            , i = h.length
            , headers
            , header_text
        ;
        while (i--) {
            headers = doc.getElementsByTagName(h[i]);
            for (var j = 0, len = headers.length; j < len; j++) {
                header_text = headers[j].textContent.trim();
                if (header_text) {
                    return header_text;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    , doc_impl = document.implementation
    , create_html_doc = function(html) {
        var
              dt = doc_impl.createDocumentType('html', null, null)
            , doc = doc_impl.createDocument("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "html", dt)
            , doc_el = doc.documentElement
            , head = doc_el.appendChild(doc.createElement("head"))
            , charset_meta = head.appendChild(doc.createElement("meta"))
            , title = head.appendChild(doc.createElement("title"))
            , body = doc_el.appendChild(doc.createElement("body"))
            , i = 0
            , len = html.childNodes.length
        ;
        charset_meta.setAttribute("charset", html.ownerDocument.characterSet);
        for (; i < len; i++) {
            body.appendChild(doc.importNode(html.childNodes.item(i), true));
        }
        var title_text = guess_title(doc);
        if (title_text) {
            title.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(title_text));
        }
        return doc;
    }
;
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 300;

  if (typeof x_points === "string") {
    x_points = JSON.parse(x_points);
} if (typeof y_points === "string") {
    y_points = JSON.parse(y_points);
} if (typeof drag_points === "string") {
    drag_points = JSON.parse(drag_points);
} if (session.canvas_filename) {
    canvas_filename.value = session.canvas_filename;
} if (session.text) {
    text.value = session.text;
} if (session.text_filename) {
    text_filename.value = session.text_filename;
} if (session.html) {
    html.innerHTML = session.html;
} if (session.html_filename) {
    html_filename.value = session.html_filename;
}

drawing = true;
draw();
drawing = false;

canvas_clear_button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
    x_points.length =
    y_points.length =
    drag_points.length =
        0;
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    drawing = true;
    add_point(event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop, false);
    draw();
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    if (drawing) {
        add_point(event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop, true);
        draw();
    }
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stop_drawing, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", stop_drawing, false);

canvas_options_form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    canvas.toBlobHD(function(blob) {
        saveAs(
              blob
            , (canvas_filename.value || canvas_filename.placeholder) + ".png"
        );
    }, "image/png");
}, false);

text_options_form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var BB = get_blob();
    saveAs(
          new BB(
              [text.value || text.placeholder]
            , {type: "text/plain;charset=" + document.characterSet}
        )
        , (text_filename.value || text_filename.placeholder) + ".txt"
    );
}, false);

html_options_form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var
          BB = get_blob()
        , xml_serializer = new XMLSerializer()
        , doc = create_html_doc(html)
    ;
    saveAs(
          new BB(
              [xml_serializer.serializeToString(doc)]
            , {type: "application/xhtml+xml;charset=" + document.characterSet}
        )
        , (html_filename.value || html_filename.placeholder) + ".xhtml"
    );
}, false);

view.addEventListener("unload", function() {
    session.x_points = JSON.stringify(x_points);
    session.y_points = JSON.stringify(y_points);
    session.drag_points = JSON.stringify(drag_points);
    session.canvas_filename = canvas_filename.value;

    session.text = text.value;
    session.text_filename = text_filename.value;

    session.html = html.innerHTML;
    session.html_filename = html_filename.value;
}, false);
}(self));
```

The html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US-x-Hixie">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>FileSaver.js demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/702cd2e820b680f88a0f299e33085c196806fc52/demo/demo.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><a href="https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js">FileSaver.js</a> demo</h1>
    <p>
        The following examples demonstrate how it is possible to generate and save any type of data right in the browser using the <code>saveAs()</code> FileSaver interface, without contacting any servers.
    </p>
    <section id="image-demo">
        <h2>Saving an image</h2>
        <canvas class="input" id="canvas" width="500" height="300"/>
        <form id="canvas-options">
            <label>Filename: <input type="text" class="filename" id="canvas-filename" placeholder="doodle"/>.png</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
            <input type="button" id="canvas-clear" value="Clear"/>
        </form>
    </section>
    <section id="text-demo">
        <h2>Saving text</h2>
        <textarea class="input" id="text" placeholder="Once upon a time..."/>
        <form id="text-options">
            <label>Filename: <input type="text" class="filename" id="text-filename" placeholder="a plain document"/>.txt</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
        </form>
    </section>
    <section id="html-demo">
        <h2>Saving rich text</h2>
        <div class="input" id="html" contenteditable="">
            <h3>Some example rich text</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><del>Plain</del> <ins>Boring</ins> text.</li>
                <li><em>Emphasized text!</em></li>
                <li><strong>Strong text!</strong></li>
                <li>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="70" height="70">
                        <circle cx="35" cy="35" r="35" fill="red"/>
                        <text x="10" y="40">image</text>
                    </svg>
                </li>
                <li><a href="https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js">A link.</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <form id="html-options">
            <label>Filename: <input type="text" class="filename" id="html-filename" placeholder="a rich document"/>.xhtml</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
        </form>
    </section>
    <script async="" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/Blob.js/0cef2746414269b16834878a8abc52eb9d53e6bd/Blob.js"/>
    <script async="" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js/f1a01896135ab378aa5c0118eadd81da55e698d8/canvas-toBlob.js"/>
    <script async="" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/e9d941381475b5df8b7d7691013401e171014e89/FileSaver.min.js"/>
    <script async="" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/597b6cd0207ce408a6d34890b5b2826b13450714/demo/demo.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `fileSaver.js` is made for browsers, not sure why you think node.js has anything to do with it

Comment: I don't know how to make it usefull, i need some sketch example to make it work without node.js

Comment: again, you mention `node.js` - this browser code has nothing to do with node.js - are you having trouble understanding the demo code? - the bits to look at are the code blocks at line 166-175, 176-187 and 188-203 - these are the blocks of code that execute `saveAs`

Comment: Yes, i did, because there is no clear explanation for how it work. You said that the browser code has nothing to do with node.js, but the Demo.js code worked without node.js. I need your explaination, and can you simplify the code which can work with another html file ?

Comment: `You said that the browser code has nothing to do with node.js` - no, I said fileSaver.js has nothing to do with node, the demo has nothing to do with node, so to make it "work without node" you do what's in the demo ...

Comment: as for writing an example ... you have an example already that you don't understand - yet the code in the example is a simple example of how to use fileSaver.js ... not sure how it can be made simpler

Comment: Oh well, thank you. I think i should learn so much about node.js, Can you show me some reference how to learn much more about node.Js ;) ?

Comment: oh my deity of choice ... why are you so focused on node.js in this question ... it has nothing to do with node.js ... at all

Comment: So, What should i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, nothing in the code you've show is related to `node.js` - so using `fileSaver.js` without `node.js` is not an issue

The simplest example I can come up with to demonstrate how to use it using a `Blob` and a `File` is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- you'll need to host fileSaver.js on your own host -->
    <script src="fileSaver.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="source">This is some text</div>
    <input id="saveFile" type="button" value="saveFile" />
    <script>
        document.getElementById('saveFile').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            var text = document.getElementById('source').innerHTML;
            var file = new File([text], "hello world.txt", {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
            // save it
            saveAs(file);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```